# Can I have github pages first link to something other than index.html

Tags: html, github, github-pages

I have a splash.html that I would like as the landing page for my project. Is there a way to configure that so that index.html is not the default link for my gitpage?
Keep in mind that I already have an index.html.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use an index file name other than the ones above, it's possible for advanced users to change the default names our servers use.

You can do this by using a .htaccess file. The file should contain a line of text like this:

> DirectoryIndex something.html

... where "something.html" is the name of the index file you want to use. (If you do this, our servers will no longer look for "index.html", "index.htm", etc. — the DirectoryIndex command completely replaces the default names.)

so the steps to follow will be

> 1- create a file named .htaccess

> 2- open the .htaccess file

> 3- write **"DirectoryIndex splash.html"** inside the file

> 4- Save the file

> 5- Commit and push to github

> 6- try again to open you website to check if it works

if you want to understand this concept more- [you can refer this](https://support.tigertech.net/index-file-names)