# Github Pages HTML file other than index.html

Tags: html, url, github-pages

### Here is my current File Structure For GITHUB PAGES:

###### Note: loading.html is my "landing page" and the file I want to load as soon as the user enters the website.

```
dist
│   CNAME
│   poster.png    
│
└───assets
│   │   css/images/js files
│   
└───src
│   │
│   └───loading-page
│       │   loading.html
│   └───main-page
│       │   main.html
```

**Here's the dilemma**: I've seen many things about `.htaccess` or `_config.yml` to route GitHub pages but they don't seem to work. Is there any way to tell GitHub to show loading.html to the user, instead of a file in the root named index.html?

**Or** is this strictly how GitHub needs to work, and there is no config file, or setting I can enable that changes this behavior? I can understand if it's strictly index.html but would love to customize the names of my .html files.

Comment: If you saw "many things" that you tried and didn't work, please make sure to include them in your post, so we can address them. `.htaccess` is an Apache httpd configuration file, and will have no effect on servers that do not run on Apache httpd, or where it is disabled. And I wish you said what exactly you saw about `_config.yml` you saw, because I can't think of a setting that would affect how the web server, which is not Jekyll but sees the statically generated site, serves the initial page.

Comment: Good questions! I've tried the link you sent me, but seems to give bad loading affects in some situations. I could try again, but was getting load times of 5s+ for some reason. 

`.htaccess` was from a YouTube Video I've watched, but I think later realized that doesn't even appear when merged into GitHub. 

`_config.yml` was a combination of ChatGPT and a YouTube video.
Code for _config.yml looked like this:

baseurl: /src/loading-page
filename: loading.html

Or 

DirectoryIndex src/loading-page/loading.html

Comment: Just realized, that DirectoryIndex is a part of .htaccess, but here are links.

`.htaccess`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72081505/can-i-have-github-pages-first-link-to-something-other-than-index-html

`_config.yml`: [https://imgur.com/a/p8VTbEN](ChatGPT), can't seem to find the YouTube video for some reason.

Comment: You could probably use the [redirect-from](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-redirect-from) Jekykll plugin.